# My code only updates the last line of my database and not the second or the one I want, only and always the last

Tags: php, sql

I have a project to render for Monday. Its purpose is simple, a form to add a user, delete and edit. My problem is on the update. I have for example three lines in my database, and I want to edit the second one, IMPOSSIBLE! my code will always update the last line of the database. If you want to test here is the site on which I test this. https://a-marie.000webhostapp.com/
    I do not really know what else to do

```
<?php
include_once("inc/connexion.php");?>
<HTML><HEAD>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<script type= text/javascript>
function confsuppr(id_personne, nom){
    if (confirm("Etes-vous surre de supprimer "+nom)){
        window.location.replace("https://a-marie.000webhostapp.com/?idsuppr="+id_personne)
        }
    }
</script>
<TITLE>personnes</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>";
<?php PRINT_R($_REQUEST);   ?><hr>
<form class="w3-container w3-light-grey"><FORM ACTION="" METHOD="POST"><legend>Ajout d'une personne :</legend>
<LABEL>Prenom : </LABEL><input class="w3-input w3-border w3-round" type="text" style="width:30%" name="prenom" required>
<LABEL>Nom : </LABEL><input class="w3-input w3-border w3-round" type="text" style="width:30%" name="nom" required>
<LABEL>E-Mail : </LABEL><input class="w3-input w3-border w3-round" type="text" style="width:30%" name="email">
<LABEL>Statut : </LABEL><input class="w3-input w3-border w3-round" type="text" style="width:30%" name="statut">
<LABEL>Date de naissance :<br/></LABEL> <input class='w3-input w3-border w3-round' type=date name="annee_naissance" required>
<INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT class='w3-button w3-block w3-teal w3-round' style='width:30%' NAME='valider' VALUE='Ajouter'>
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['valider'])=="Ajouter") {
    $prenom=mysqli_real_escape_string($cnx, $_REQUEST['prenom']);
    $nom=mysqli_real_escape_string($cnx, $_REQUEST['nom']);
    $annee_naissance=$_REQUEST['annee_naissance'];
    $email=mysqli_real_escape_string($cnx,$_REQUEST['email']);
    //$statut=$_REQUEST['statut'];
    $statut=mysqli_real_escape_string($cnx,$_REQUEST['statut']);
    $req="INSERT INTO personnes VALUES(NULL,'$nom','$annee_naissance','$prenom','$email','$statut');";
    $result=mysqli_query($cnx,$req); if(!$result) $msg="requete invalide : ".mysqli_error(); else $msg=$req;
}
if (isset($_REQUEST['idsuppr'])!="") {
    $supprid=$_REQUEST['idsuppr'];
    $req="DELETE FROM personnes WHERE id_personne='$supprid';";
    $result=mysqli_query($cnx,$req); if(!$result) $msg="requete invalide : ".mysqli_error(); else $msg=$req;
}
if (isset($_REQUEST['maj'])!="") {
    $id_personne=$_REQUEST['id_personne'];
    //$id_personne = $_GET['maj'];
    $prenom=ucfirst(mysqli_real_escape_string($cnx,$_REQUEST['prenom']));
    $nom=strtoupper(mysqli_real_escape_string($cnx,$_REQUEST['nom']));
    $annee_naissance=$_REQUEST['annee_naissance'];
    $email=mysqli_real_escape_string($cnx,$_REQUEST['email']);
    $statut=mysqli_real_escape_string($cnx,$_REQUEST['statut']);
    $req="UPDATE personnes SET nom='$nom',annee_naissance='$annee_naissance',prenom='$prenom',email='$email',statut='$statut' WHERE id_personne='$id_personne';";
    $result=mysqli_query($cnx,$req); if(!$result) $msg="requete invalide : ".mysqli_error(); else $msg=$req;
}
$str="<div class='w3-container'><table class=w3-table-all w3-hoverable><caption>Personnes</caption><thead><TR class='w3-light-grey'><TH>Id</TH><TH>Prenom</TH><TH>Nom</TH><TH>Naiss</TH><TH>EMAIL</TH><TH>Statut</TH><TH>Suppr</TH><TH>maj</TH></TR></thead>";
$req="SELECT * FROM personnes ORDER BY id_personne ASC;";
$result=mysqli_query($cnx,$req); if(!$result) $msg="requete invalide : ".mysqli_error();
//$result=mysqli_query($cnx,$req); $msg="requete invalide : ".mysqli_error(); $msg=$req;
else{
    foreach ($result as $ligne) {
    $str.="<TR><FORM METHOD='POST' ACTION=''>";
        $prenom=$ligne["prenom"];
        $nom=$ligne["nom"];
        $id_personne=$ligne["id_personne"];
        $ddn=$ligne["annee_naissance"];
        $email=$ligne["email"];
        $statut=$ligne["statut"];
        $str.="<TD><input type=hidden name=id_personne value='$id_personne'></TD>";
        $str.="<TR><TD>".$id_personne."</TD>";
        $str.="<TD><input class='w3-input' type=text name='prenom' value=$prenom></TD><TD><input class='w3-input' type=text name='nom' value=$nom></TD><TD><input class='w3-input' type=date name='annee_naissance' value=$ddn></TD><TD><input type=email name='email' value=$email></TD><TD><input type=text name='statut' value=$statut></TD>";
        $str.="<TD><input class='w3-input' type=button onclick=confsuppr($id_personne,\"$nom\"); value=Suppr></TD>";
        $str.="<TD><input class='w3-input' type=submit NAME=maj value=maj /><input type=hidden name=id_personne value=$ligne[id_personne] />  </TD></TR>";

    }
    }    
$str.="</TABLE></div>"; echo $str;?>
<div class="w3-row"><div class="w3-twothird w3-container">
<div class="w3-panel w3-amber"><p><?php if (isset($msg)) {    echo $msg;}else{echo $req;}   ?><p></div>
</div></div>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: Check were your `<form>` tags are closed (`<FORM METHOD='POST' ACTION=''>` especially)

Comment: there are some serious issues with this code - I'd strongly suggest using a prepared statements. There are nested forms, forms using GET.. `<form class="w3-container w3-light-grey"><FORM ACTION="" METHOD="POST">`

Comment: you use GET for one form which generates a querystring when adding a user - simply reloading the page will add a new user after that. The form should use POST

Answer (score 1):

close your **form tag**

```
  $str.="<TR><FORM METHOD='POST' ACTION=''>";
        $prenom=$ligne["prenom"];
        $nom=$ligne["nom"];
        $id_personne=$ligne["id_personne"];
        $ddn=$ligne["annee_naissance"];
        $email=$ligne["email"];
        $statut=$ligne["statut"];
        $str.="<TD><input type=hidden name=id_personne value='$id_personne'></TD>";
        $str.="<TR><TD>".$id_personne."</TD>";
        $str.="<TD><input class='w3-input' type=text name='prenom' value=$prenom></TD><TD><input class='w3-input' type=text name='nom' value=$nom></TD><TD><input class='w3-input' type=date name='annee_naissance' value=$ddn></TD><TD><input type=email name='email' value=$email></TD><TD><input type=text name='statut' value=$statut></TD>";
        $str.="<TD><input class='w3-input' type=button onclick=confsuppr($id_personne,\"$nom\"); value=Suppr></TD>";
        $str.="<TD><input class='w3-input' type=submit NAME=maj value=maj /><input type=hidden name=id_personne value=$ligne[id_personne] /> 
//close your form  
 </TD></Form></TR>";
```

Comment: That is invalid HTML - the FORM cannot contain the TD element like that - it must either be entirely within the TD or entirely outside the whole table to be valid

Comment: Agreed. You might as well create a new table for each row, unless you are ready to involve some javascript.  Learn some JQuery if you haven't already (for future projects)

Answer (score 0):

Along with closing the form properly, you need to encapsulate the HTML within the form correctly. The easiest way is to create a new table for each row and wrap the table with the form element.

```
$str="<div class='w3-container'><table class=w3-table-all w3-hoverable><caption>Personnes</caption><thead><TR class='w3-light-grey'><TH>Id</TH><TH>Prenom</TH><TH>Nom</TH><TH>Naiss</TH><TH>EMAIL</TH><TH>Statut</TH><TH>Suppr</TH><TH>maj</TH></TR></thead></table>";
$req="SELECT * FROM personnes ORDER BY id_personne ASC;";
$result=mysqli_query($cnx,$req); if(!$result) $msg="requete invalide : ".mysqli_error();
//$result=mysqli_query($cnx,$req); $msg="requete invalide : ".mysqli_error(); $msg=$req;
else{
    foreach ($result as $ligne) {
    $str.="<FORM METHOD='POST' ACTION=''><TABLE><TR>";
        $prenom=$ligne["prenom"];
        $nom=$ligne["nom"];
        $id_personne=$ligne["id_personne"];
        $ddn=$ligne["annee_naissance"];
        $email=$ligne["email"];
        $statut=$ligne["statut"];
        $str.="<TD><input type=hidden name=id_personne value='$id_personne'></TD>";
        $str.="<TR><TD>".$id_personne."</TD>";
        $str.="<TD><input class='w3-input' type=text name='prenom' value=$prenom></TD><TD><input class='w3-input' type=text name='nom' value=$nom></TD><TD><input class='w3-input' type=date name='annee_naissance' value=$ddn></TD><TD><input type=email name='email' value=$email></TD><TD><input type=text name='statut' value=$statut></TD>";
        $str.="<TD><input class='w3-input' type=button onclick=confsuppr($id_personne,\"$nom\"); value=Suppr></TD>";
        $str.="<TD><input class='w3-input' type=submit NAME=maj value=maj /><input type=hidden name=id_personne value=$ligne[id_personne] />  </TD></TR>";
        $str.="</TABLE></FORM>";
    }
    }    
$str.="</div>"; echo $str;?>
```